# How to perform tf.image.per_image_standardization on a batch of images in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, batch-processing, image-whitening

I would like to know how to perform image whitening on a batch of images.

According to the documentation in https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/per_image_standardization, it is said that `tf.image.per_image_standardization` takes as input a 3D tensor, that is an image, of shape: `[height, width, channels]`.

Is it a missing feature or there is a different method?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: usually, Tf pipelines involves preprocessing on single image and queuing them to generate batches. For example: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/image_processing.py

Comment: @HarshaPokkalla, link rot!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is how to perform this operation on a batch of images.

`tf.map_fn(lambda frame: tf.image.per_image_standardization(frame), frames)`

Comment: Can you explain your solution? What does the function return? What is `lambda`, `frame` and `frames`?

Comment: `tf.image.per_image_standardization` takes takes as input 1 image at a time. `tf.map_fn` is used to apply a function on every instance of a batch. The batch here is `frames` and each instance of that is a `frame`. As for the lambda, this is pythonic way to create a callable method; which the `tf.map_fn` requires as input. Hope this help

Comment: You can now give the function directly a batch of images in tf 1.14 before it was working only on single images.